# positioning issue with hyper link

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` containing simple text. I should show only 3 lines of that text with `showMore` link. on clicking of showMore link I need to show all the text inside it with `showLess` link. Right now I am using `overflow` property to achieve this. But have a small problem that I should show `"showMore"` link immediately after the text. So how can I position the hyperlink inside the text?

My Code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.showMore').click(function (event) {
        var contentDiv = jQuery('.contentDiv');
        contentDiv[0].style.height = 'auto';
        jQuery(event.target).hide();
        jQuery('.showLess').show();
    });
    jQuery('.showLess').click(function (event) {
        var contentDiv = jQuery('.contentDiv');
        var lineHeight = getLineHeight(contentDiv[0]);
        contentDiv[0].style.height = lineHeight * 3 + 'px';
        jQuery(event.target).hide();
        jQuery('.showMore').show();
    });
});


<!doctype html>
    <html>

    <body >
<div>
<div class = "contentDiv">
some content <br r1<br> r2<br> r3 <br> r4<br> r5
    </div>      
<a href = '#'  class = "showMore">Show More</a>
<a href = '#'  class = "showLess">Show Less</a>     
</div>
    </body>
    </html>


.contentDiv a {
    float : right;
 }
.contentDiv {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:3.6em;
    background:#ccc;
font-size : 12pt ;
    font-family :Courier;
 }
.showMore {
    float: right;
}
.showLess {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display : none;
margin-bottom : 5px
}
```

Comment: can you post your code what you have done upto

Comment: You want to edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: pleaselook into teh code and let me knoe my fault

Comment: You're asking a question tagged with HTML and CSS but don't paste that into the question body? Try that. It might help.

Comment: sorry I am new to this,please have a look on my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one of the million ways you could achieve this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLFJF/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="text">Lots of text..</div>
<a href="#" id="showmore">Show More</a>
<a href="#" id="showless">Show Less</a>
```

CSS

```
#text {height:55px;overflow:hidden;}
#showless {display:none;}
```

jQuery

```
$('#showmore').on('click', function(e){
    $('#text').css('overflow', 'visible').css('height', 'auto');
    $('#showless').show();
    $(this).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#showless').on('click', function(e){
    $('#text').css('overflow', 'hidden').css('height', '55px');
    $('#showmore').show();
    $(this).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

To position the 'show more' in the bottom right (as requested in your follow-up comment), put the `<a>` tag inside the div and position it absolutely. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLFJF/4/)

HTML

```
<div id="text">Lots of text..
    <a href="#" id="showmore">Show More</a>
</div>
<a href="#" id="showless">Show Less</a>
```

CSS

```
#text {height:55px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
#showmore {position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;background:#fff;padding-left:10px;}
#showless{display:none;}
```

Comment: Hi i have tried it but it is showing all the text and then show more link

Comment: @madhulatha Click the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLFJF/2/), look at the pane in the bottom right corner and you'll see it works.  If you are referring to this change not working on your own code, then we can't tell what is wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: ya now it is working. but i need small change in this . th show more link should appear at the end of third line. that means the text should  truncate and link should come there